# Which directory does monero-blockchain-import, by default, use to store the imported blockchain?

Tags: monero-wallet-gui, blockchain, blockchain-import, blockchain-data

I am not sure if this makes sense or not.  I was using an old version of the Monero GUI and I was stuck at block 140001.  I thought it was a sycning problem so I downloaded the raw blockchain from getmonero.  Then I followed these [instructions](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/3243/how-to-synchronize-the-gui-wallet-using-the-blockchain-bootstrap?noredirect=1)

When I followed those instructions, my terminal gave me an error (after loading most of the blockchain) that there wasn't enough space to load the block chain on my computer. I check my HD and I had 9GB left.  I started with 32GB.   My GUI program was on my 32GB HD and the blockchain was located on a 2TB HD.

So now that I've updated my GUI to the newest version, it's syncing fine, but I still only have 9GB left on my Mac HD.  Where do delete the files that were created during the failed bootstrapping?

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This question basically pertains to where `monero-blockchain-import` stores the imported blockchain by default. `monero-blockchain-import` uses the following default directories to store the imported blockchain:

**Windows:**

`C:\ProgramData\bitmonero\lmdb`

**Linux and Mac OS X:**

`~/.bitmonero/lmdb`

Note that, by default, both `C:\ProgramData\bitmonero\lmdb` and `~/.bitmonero/lmdb` are hidden directories. On Windows, you have to use the explorer to manually navigate to aforementioned directory. On Mac OS X, you can typically use <kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>.</kbd> to unhide directories. On Linux, you can typically use <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> to unhide directories.

> Where do delete the files that were created during the failed bootstrapping?

Thus, to delete redundant data, you should delete aforementioned directory.

---

`monero-blockchain-import` also allows one to import the blockchain to a custom data directory. This is done as follows:

**Windows:**

Open a new command prompt from the same directory as `monero-blockchain-import.exe`. This is done by first making sure your cursor isn't located on any of the files and subsequently doing <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>right click</kbd>. It will give you an option to "Open command window here". If you're using Windows 10, it'll, most likely, give you an option to open the Powershell.

Subsequently, type the following command in the command prompt:

```
monero-blockchain-import.exe --input-file path\to\blockchain.raw --data-dir path\to\preferred\data\directory
```

If that doesn't work in the Powershell, type:

```
.\monero-blockchain-import.exe --input-file path\to\blockchain.raw --data-dir path\to\preferred\data\directory
```

If that doesn't work either in the Powershell, type:

```
./monero-blockchain-import.exe --input-file path\to\blockchain.raw --data-dir path\to\preferred\data\directory
```

**Linux and Mac OS X:**

Open a new terminal from the same directory as `monero-blockchain-import`.

*Sidenote:* On Mac OS X, you probably can only open a terminal from the desktop. As a result, you have to use `cd` to navigate to the directory of `monero-blockchain-import` first. For example, if `monero-blockchain-import` is located in `~/Applications/monero-wallet-gui.app/Contents/MacOS` you'd have to type `cd ~/Applications/monero-wallet-gui.app/Contents/MacOS` to ensure the terminal is in the proper directory.

Subsequently, type the following command in the terminal.

```
./monero-blockchain-import --input-file path/to/blockchain.raw --data-dir path/to/preferred/data/directory
```

> Where do delete the files that were created during the failed bootstrapping?

Thus, if you used the `--data-dir` flag, you should delete the directory you specified to delete redundant data.