# Why does the option "--verify 0" for monero-blockchain-import not work?

Tags: monero-wallet-cli, blockchain, synchronization, blockchain-import, issue

When I use the command `./monero-blockchain-import --verify 0 --input-file ./blockchain.raw` it says *"Failed to parse arguments: unrecognised option '--verify'"*.

Comment: Unfortuately, pages like https://ww.getmonero.org/resources/user-guides/importing_blockchain.html tell you to do it with downloaded files from the internet.

Comment: Also, answers on StackExchange like https://monero.stackexchange.com/a/3796/9994 also tell you to do it with downloaded files from the internet.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

People were abusing --verify 0, using it for files they downloaded from the internet, which is a dangerous thing to do. So it got renamed to `--dangerous-unverified-import` (prior to this it was named `--guard-against-pwnage`), to make it clear it's a dangerous thing to do. Similar to disabling a malware scanner when downloading some binary off the internet.

Or, sadly, people using third party nodes even though you should run your own for privacy.

Oh well. Maybe that battle is lost. People like overriding safety mechanisms.