# Is there a secure way to boostrap a node?

Tags: synchronization

It seems the sync process is tediously slow with it's verification. I do know of the bootstrap file, but I'm not sure how secure this is ([How to synchronize the GUI wallet using the blockchain bootstrap](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/3243/how-to-synchronize-the-gui-wallet-using-the-blockchain-bootstrap/3796#3796) seems to state that verification is disabled for this)? There isn't even a known hash given for the bootstrap file?

Is there a known state of the blockchain that is hashed / verified somewhere?

Comment: Downloading and importing the raw blockchain is slower than just letting your daemon sync of the network.

Answer (score 1):

You are probably looking for [bootstrap node](https://web.getmonero.org/resources/moneropedia/bootstrap-node.html)

`monerod --help`

```
  --bootstrap-daemon-address arg        URL of a 'bootstrap' remote daemon that
                                        the connected wallets can use while 
                                        this daemon is still not fully synced.
                                        Use 'auto' to enable automatic public 
                                        nodes discovering and bootstrap daemon 
                                        switching
```